# How to make the Enter button do something else rather than submit a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form in which I use autocomplete, and a link.  When some text is entered into the form, and the link is clicked, the contents of the text go into the the textarea.

You can see it working in this test page: http://www.problemio.com/test.php

The problem I am having is that when the cursor is in the textfield, and "enter" is pressed, the form gets submitted.  But the more intuitive thing is that the "add category" link gets clicked.

Is there a way to change things so that when the cursor is on the textfield, and enter is pressed, the page acts as though the link for "add category" is pressed?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about to use a normal button instead of submit. You can bind click to it and do what you want even submit a form.

Comment: Well, actually, on second thought, the problem is that there isn't a click to that button whenever the uses presses enter.  What I need is to somehow catch the event when the user presses enter from the textfield.

Comment: Hmm the point is, by default behavior submit buttons in a form, submits the form automatically by pressing Enter on any text field. But the rule is not valid for normal buttons. You can submit your form manually.

Comment: Btw, submit button is more semantic in a form rather than normal button. If you want to use it, you can simply prevent default behavior by event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 2):

You can override the pressing of the Enter in the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function stopRKey(evt) {
  var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
  var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
  if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;}
}

document.onkeypress = stopRKey;

</script>
```

Comment: You could replace the `evt` assignment with `evt = evt || event`. The same goes for `node`.

Comment: @Romario thanks...not sure I completely understand what is happening here.  Could you help me understand what that code is doing and in what sequence it gets executed?  Thanks!!

Comment: first - we try to get the event in the function. If it is null we get window.event instead

Comment: then we get the node. If the node type is text and event key code is 13 (enter) then we return false, so event doesn't fire. Main thing to know is "? :" - look here http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/javascript/ternary.php

Answer (score 1):

You can add the onsubmit event to your form tag. So it looks like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return doSubmit();">
```

Then in your JavaScript you can have:

```
function doSubmit() {
    //Do all your JS stuff here
    document.getElementById("addCategoryId").click(); //Not sure if this is completely right, but that will click your addCategory button/link as long as the ID is set correctly.

    return false; //Don't submit form
}
```

Comment: Thanks - but in the part of the doSubmit() where I do the JS, how do I tell where the cursor was? Is that possible?